# Obtaining interpolating functions from NDSolve with two functions

Tags: differential-equations, interpolation

In Mathematica's documentation on interpolating functions, they give an example of how to obtain an interpolating function as a solution of `NDSolve`,

```
ifun = First[
  u /. NDSolve[{u''[t] + u[t] == 0, u[0] == 0, u'[0] == 1}, 
    u, {t, 0, \[Pi]}]]
```

I would like to do something similar, but with two functions. For example, `NDSolve` might look something like

```
NDSolve[{u'[t] + v[t] == 0, v'[t] + u[t] == 0, u[0] == 0, v[0] == 1}, 
        {u, v}, {t, 0, \[Pi]}]]
```

This returns a list of two interpolating functions, but I'm just a bit confused by how to turn that into two functions that can be called like normal functions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sol = NDSolve[{u'[t] + v[t] == 0, v'[t] + u[t] == 0, u[0] == 0, v[0] == 1}, 
       {u, v}, {t, 0, \[Pi]}]

{{u, v}} = {u, v} /. sol

Plot[{u[x], v[x]}, {x, 0, Pi}]
```

[image]